# Whats the best way to fix HTML Layout problems?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a site where I'm trying to modify a chat applet (a javascript applet loaded from off-site).  I'm positioning a graphic over part of it and adding some code to expand it when I'm not online/available (it will show a form, and I want the whole form to be visible).

Everything works fine, except that the positioning will fail on either Chrome or Firefox.  When I fix one, it breaks the other.  I'm thinking of using browser detection to fix it, but the positioning I'm using is pretty simple.  I'm wondering if one browser or the other isn't following a standard, or am I doing something wrong?  Basically, the image I'm putting over the applet is taking up space on the page and pushing the chat applet down in some instances and not in others.

Mobile and Desktop support required (currently displays the same on each).  Page in question is too big to post here but I'll give a link so you can view the source (currently has hacks to display correctly on Firefox, and Chrome shows a large gap).  https://eddon.systems/joomla/index.php/contact-evan

Here's the code in question:

```
<div id="chat-height" style="height: 24em;">

<div id="ed" class="pull-right" style="z-index: 1000006; position:relative; right: 0; top: -3em;">
  <img src="/img/grasshopper.png" />
</div>

<div id='tawk_55b4804ed05623730af6f54a' style="position: relative; top: 0em;"></div>
<!--Start of Tawk.to Script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
var $_Tawk_API={embedded:'tawk_55b4804ed05623730af6f54a'},$_Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
(function(){
var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
s1.async=true;
s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/55b4804ed05623730af6f54a/19r4labog';
s1.charset='UTF-8';
s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);})();

$_Tawk_API.onStatusChange = function(status){
  if (status === 'offline'){
        document.getElementById('chat-height').style.height="38em";
        document.getElementById('tawkchat-maximized-iframe-element').style.height="38em";
        document.getElementsByClassName("contact-mobile")[0].style.visibility="visible";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('chat-height').style.height="24em";
    document.getElementById('tawkchat-maximized-iframe-element').style.height="23.5em";
    document.getElementsByClassName("contact-mobile")[0].style.visibility="hidden";
  }
}

</script>
<!--End of Tawk.to Script-->
</div>
```

Comment: The best way to start is to put actual code in the question.

Comment: no relevant code posted...site advertising

Comment: question are too broad, should put on hold..

Comment: Not advertising.  But since half the page is generated by Joomla, posting the entire generated html would much too large.  Posting only what I have added (as a module - which is not in the question) may not have enough information to fix the problem, which is why I felt the link was a better option.

Comment: @StackOverflow How is this too broad?  The question is pretty specific.  There's already an answer for it which works and is not *"too long for this format"*.

Comment: @divinecomedian Yes it does indeed fix the problem, and if I knew how to narrow down the solution set I wouldn't be asking here!  I would just Google it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is with this element: `<div id="ed">`. It is a `<div>` with `position:relative;`, meaning it will display block and any element after it will be put on a new line, which is what is creating the gap.

To fix it try updating your style for the wrapping div by adding a `position:relative;` like this:

```
#chat-height{
    position:relative;
}
```

Then change the style of your `<div id="ed">` to `position:absolute;` in order to position it absolutely to your wrapping div.

Comment: Well, originally I didn't even have that in their as I was relying on Joomla's module code to wrap everything  and added that in hoping it would help.  I was on the right track, but the fact that it worked in one browser and not the other is what threw me.   I guess one needs "relative" and the other doesn't care.   This does indeed work with both browsers (I don't care about IE or Safari) and I can throw out the hacks to set the size since auto sizing works properly as well.  SOLVED!  Thank you!!